Why is there a spelling error appearing for flutter_slidable?
I wanted to use a slidable widget for my to-do list app so I attempted to add the flutter_slidable widget to my pubspec.yaml. However, there is always a spelling error with the message: Typo: In word 'slidable'. This is part of my code:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_slidable: ^3.1.0

I made sure my flutter SDK version was up to date. I tried running 'flutter clean' and 'flutter build' as well. However, the problem was not fixed. I thought this spelling error message might be something I could just ignore so I proceeded to use it in one of my coding files. However when I tried to wrap my container in the slidable widget, it displayed the error message:

The typo error is just a warning, and you can ignore it. It won't cause any error on your application. If you don't want to see it, please save it to dictionary. Then your IDE won't bug you more.
